# Is there a way to submit a form without a submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am writing a form, and I may be overcomplicating this, but I want the form to change based on the response to a question. It is a contact form. I want to ask a question, then use a php if else statement to generate the response do if a show this haml, elseif b show this. In the end the form will be emailed to me. Here is my question. If i set the variables in the head section like this:

```
<?php
    $letter = $_POST['letter'];
    ?>
    </html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <select name="letter'>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($letter == a) {html}
    elseif ($letter == b) {html}
    ?>
```

Would that work, or does the form need to be submited before the variable can be assigned? If it needs to be submited, can that be done as soon as the selection is made in the select tag and how would I do that without the user clicking a submit button?

Comment: Things don't work like that when you're dealing with back end processing (server-side scripts like PHP). To your goals concerning dynamic HTML change on the fly, you should research about using Javascript.

Comment: This is where JS comes in.

Comment: It would not work, as you guessed, the form needs to be submitted, php runs on the server only. or you could look into using ajax

Comment: You want submit form on select change ?

Comment: Aside, a few hints: match starting and closing quote styles. Close the select tag.

Comment: ... after the last `</option>` and before the `</form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

yes using javascript(jQuery) you can submit form without refreshing page.!

follow these steps and create files

**Example.php**

```
<html>
<head>
   <!--include jquery and js code -->
   <script type="javascript/text" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="javascript/text" src="myjs.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
      <select name="letter' id="letter">
          <option value="a">a</option>
          <option value="b">b</option>
      </select>
     </form>
     <div id="response"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#letter").change(function(){
           $.post("process.php", { letter: $(this).val() },function(r){
                 $("#response").html(r);
           });
     });
});
```

**Now final process.php**

now in process.php you can do process like that

```
<?php
$letter = $_POST['letter'];
if ($letter == a) {html}
elseif ($letter == b) {html}
?>
```